# Combined rows with same id in to one row keeping all data

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table with a number of records for plants. A plant can have a number of names the table shows this as different records. The table is called new_plantsname

```
plantid name
1       tree
1       rose
2       bush
3       tree
3       bush
3       rose
```

This continues for over 3000 records

What I want is it to combined records with same plantid and show the different names in different columns:

```
plantid name1 name2 name3 ...
1       tree  rose  NULL
2       shrub NULL  NULL
3       tree  rose  bush
```

Etc

I also want to save results to a new table

Comment: Will `select group_concat(name) from new_plantsname group by plantid` do?  (Assuming MySQL)

Comment: Is it useful to find max ID for the plants and then use PIVOT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT` (you did not specify RDBMS) I am assuming MySQL and it does not have a `PIVOT` function so you will need to replicate this using an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement. This solution adds a `rownumber` to each row so you can determine how many `name` values you need to transform to columns.

If you know how many `name` values you are going to have you can hard-code the values:

```
select plantid,
  max(case when nameRn = 'name1' then name end) Name1,
  max(case when nameRn = 'name2' then name end) Name2,
  max(case when nameRn = 'name3' then name end) Name3
from
(
  select plantid, name,
      concat('name', @num := if(@plantid = `plantid`, @num + 1, 1)) as nameRn,
      @plantid := `plantid` as dummy
  from
  (
    select plantid, name, @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
    from yourtable, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
  ) x
  order by plantid, overall_row_num
) src
group by plantid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86b39/14)

If you have an unknown number of values, then you can use a prepared statement to generate a dynamic version of this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when nameRn = ''',
      nameRn,
      ''' then name end) AS ',
      nameRn
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM 
(
  select plantid, name,
      concat('name', @num := if(@plantid = `plantid`, @num + 1, 1)) as nameRn,
      @plantid := `plantid` as dummy
  from
  (
    select plantid, name, @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
    from yourtable, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
  ) x
  order by plantid, overall_row_num
) src;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT plantid, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM 
                  (
                    select plantid, name,
                        concat(''name'', @num := if(@plantid = `plantid`, @num + 1, 1)) as nameRn,
                        @plantid := `plantid` as dummy
                    from
                    (
                      select plantid, name, @rn:=@rn+1 overall_row_num
                      from yourtable, (SELECT @rn:=0) r
                    ) x
                    order by plantid, overall_row_num
                  ) src
                   GROUP BY plantid');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11c88/1)

Both will generate the same result:

```
| PLANTID | NAME1 |  NAME2 |  NAME3 |
-------------------------------------
|       1 |  tree |   rose | (null) |
|       2 |  bush | (null) | (null) |
|       3 |  tree |   bush |   rose |
```

Comment: thanks this is great would vote answer up but new to site so cant yet

Comment: I am doing this in wamp phpmyadmin and getting an error:  #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Comment: @zaratjlc I am unable to reproduce the error you say you are getting.

Comment: @zaratjlc I am unsure why you unaccepted this answer and then posted a new question with your issue.

Comment: Sorry a friend told me if it didnt work to unaccept answer as it closes the question I am getting a error with the code you showed it is:  #1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE

Comment: @zaratjlc The problem is now you have opened another question with the same issue causing a duplicate.  So you will need to either accept this one, or delete the other one.

Comment: I am getting the error in the wamp phpmyadmin sql generator I am using wampserver version 2.2 php version 5.4.3

Comment: @zaratjlc I will see if I can recreate the issue and post an answer on your other question.

Comment: Thanks the table does have other columns but I only need plantid and names pulled through to a new table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19650/discussion-between-zaratjlc-and-bluefeet)